# Extract key from array

Tags: php

I just wonder if i can get the keys from below code

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST); //this will return all key
$key = array_key($_POS['username']) //i dont know this this is possible, im trying to get the 'username'
```

is it possible?

Comment: username is the key here - the value will be whatever this evaluates to

Comment: I don't get it. In this case, you know beforehand what key you are going to use, so there is no need to get the key. Can you show a more relevant use case?

Comment: @genesis that what it is, get the key from single $_POST data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_keys($_POST);`](http://us.php.net/array_keys)

for the single key:

```
list($key) = array_keys($_POST);
```

or

```
reset($_POST);
$key = key($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

slier, are you looking for

```
array_keys($_POST);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the keys with something like `array_keys($_POST)`.

If you just want to know whether a "username" was posted, `isset($_POST['username'])` would work.

But if you're trying to take `$_POST['username']` and know that its key was "username", you won't be able to reliably do that short of looping through the array like `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)`.

Comment: that what i been thinking..i dont think it possible though

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array_key_exists('username',$_POST)){
   $_POST['username'];
}
```

or

```
for ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   //Iterate and use $key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_keys($_POST)
```

is what you're looking for